# Some books about plane Affine geometry?

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I want to learn some introductive notions about next topics: Plane affine geometry ( Axioms, Theorems, Models), The group of affine transformations of a vector space, Affine invariants. I need a book for beginners.

Comment: Geometry by Michele Audin, edited by Springer Verlag,Universitext

Comment: There is a big ambiguity in the term "affine geometry". By "affine geometry" don't you mean in fact  "affine differential geometry" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_differential_geometry which is totally distinct field of what 95% of people doing mathematics name "affine geometry" ?